# NoMethodError in CirclesController#add undefined method `circle' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby

This is the error I got:

Extracted source (around line #14):

```
12 
13  # Current_user wants to room with user_to. Neither have a circle. Create a new circle and add both
14  if current_user.circle.empty? && user.circle.empty?
15     circle = Circle.new
16     circle.users << current_user
17     circle.users << user
```

Here is the screenshot
https://i.stack.imgur.com/jG198.png

```
**CIRCLE CONTRONER**
class CirclesController < ApplicationController
    def index
        @circles = Circle.all
    end

    def add
        # binding.pry 
        # if !current_user.landlord && current_user.memberships.any? 
        #     redirect_to user_path(current_user), notice: 'You already have a circle! Leave your current circle to join a different one.' 
        # else 
            @circle = Circle.add_user_to_circle(current_user, params[:user_to_add])

        if @circle && @circle.save
            redirect_to user_path(current_user), notice: 'Member was successfully added to circle!'
        elsif @circle == false
            redirect_to user_path(current_user), notice: 'User already in circle!' 
        else
            redirect_to user_path(current_user), notice: 'An error occurred, and the member could not be added to a circle.'
        end 
        # end
    end

    def show
         @circle = Circle.all
    end
end
```

Above code is the CircleController. I have no idea what is wrong here.
Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: You might want to fix the formatting. But your error indicates that a user is not signed in — thus, `current_user` is nil.

Comment: You have not asked a question.  See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

In line #14 you should check if **current_user** is initialized before use any method of it.

Change
`if current_user.circle.empty? && user.circle.empty?`
to
`if current_user && current_user.circle.empty? && user.circle.empty?`
or
`if !current_user.nil? && current_user.circle.empty? && user.circle.empty?`

It won't solve your other problems, but prevent **NoMethodError** error.
Furthermore, you may want to check **circle** same way before use method **#empty**?

I haven't analyzed your code in deep, but it standard practice to check some object if it's exist (if it may not) before use it.